# Proxies Requests is using my own ip and when I'm using https I'm getting error

Tags: python, python-requests, proxies

Proxies Requests is using my own ip and when I'm using https I'm getting error:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I'm really trying to solve it and didn't found a working solution.

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far?

Comment: ` s = requests.session()
    ddddsadadads = s.get("https://api.myip.com", proxies = {"https": 'https://190.8.46.90:6969'})
    print(ddddsadadads.content)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a code snippet that should work in your case.

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://190.8.46.90:6969',
  'https': 'http://190.8.46.90:6969',
}
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update(proxies)

s.get('https://api.myip.com')
```

You should also check for a firewall issue, the main cause of a connection timeout.

Comment: hmmm not working, its still using my own ip

Comment: If your mean your proxy does not act as a proxy and just routes the packages without changing the source IP? So I think the problem is a proxy misconfiguration not your code. It seems another issue unrelated to the timeout while setting a proxy.